# При нажатии на кнопку хочу вызвать только Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, но вызываются все соцсети

Tags: android, android-intent

Для обратной связи при нажатии на кнопку хотел чтобы вызывалась только почта, а вызывается длинный список разных программ. Может я не так поставил фильтр?

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                 shareIntent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
                 shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "trinka.online@gmail.com" });
                 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Вопрос:");
                 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "текст вопроса");
                 startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы сразу открывалась почта?

Comment: Да.Хотелось бы .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы используете не тот Action. Надо так

```
Intent intentEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:" + emailAddress));
```

Comment: Всё работает) Огромное спасибо!